# uwsgi worker processes keep running

Tags: django, uwsgi

I am using emperor mode and noticed a couple of uwsgi worker processes keep using CPU.

Here is the ini config for the particular website

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/%n.sock
master = true
processes = 2
env = DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=abc.settings
module = django.core.handlers.wsgi:WSGIHandler()
pythonpath = /var/www/abc/abc
chdir = /var/www/abc/abc
chmod-socket = 666
uid = www-data
virtualenv = /var/www/abc
vacuum = true
procname-prefix-spaced = %n
plugins = python
enable-threads = true
single-interpreter = true
sharedarea = 4
```

htop shows:

```
13658 www-data   20   0  204M 59168  4148 S  3.0  3.5  3h03:50 abc uWSGI worker 1
13659 www-data   20   0  209M 65092  4428 S  1.0  3.8  3h02:02 abc uWSGI worker 2
```

I have checked nginx and uwsgi log and both not showing the site is be accessed.

The question is:

why the workers keep using around 1-5% of the CPU when the site is not being accessed.

Comment: why the workers keep using around 1-5% of the CPU when the site is not being accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the cause of this, in development, I am using the timer to monitor code changes then reload the uwsgi processes, and I think it's because the project is using django-cms and it's kind of big, so constantly monitoring for code changes every second is kind of heavy, after changing the timer to 5 seconds the processes actually gone quiet.